# Angular2 calling facebook login api from asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, facebook, angular

In my ASP.NET Core application I have made facebook login, which works fine. In my Controller there are two methods to make that facebook login

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string remoteError = null)
```

ExternalLogin makes the request to facebook and opens the approval page. When I click Continue in that approval page ExternalLoginCallback is called.

Now the problem is that I made api calls to these two actions and I am using them in my Angular2 application.

So when I click facebook login button in angular2 app my ExternalLogin action is called and it returns success response, because facebook approval page is opened, but now I can't get ant response from ExternalLoginCallback, which is called automatically. How could I get the wanted response in my facebookLogin method???

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "User", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}

[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string remoteError = null)
{
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteError))
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(401);
    }
    if (info == null)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(401);
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, false, true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(200);
    }

    //Register with facebook
    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(401);
    }
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = email,
        Email = email
    };
    var createResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
    if (createResult.Succeeded)
    {
        createResult = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(_userManager.Users.First(m => m.Email == user.Email), info);
        if (createResult.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, false, true);
            return new StatusCodeResult(200);
        }
    }

    return new StatusCodeResult(401);
}
```

This is my typescript method of subscribing the api call:

```
facebookLogin(provider: string, returnUrl: string) {
    this.productService.externalLogin(provider, returnUrl).subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);

    },
    error => {
    });
}
```

And this is my api call:

```
public externalLogin(provider: string, returnUrl: string) {
    var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/api/User/ExternalLogin?Provider=Facebook&ReturnUrl=%2F';

    return this.http.post(url, `Provider=${provider}&ReturnUrl=${returnUrl}`);
}
```